# Python Programming with raspberry Pi...Import mysqldb error

Tags: python, mysql

[update Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkqzv.png)  [Installation Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIt4c.png)I am trying to access a database using python.when i am executing my script its giving error, Import Error:-No module named MySQL . I have even tried it to run with lower versions of python but the same error came.I tried to install the MySQL package using the command sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb but it throwing some error.

Comment: Add the error traceback

Comment: Did you try install `python-mysqldb`?  `sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb`

Comment: please post your `some error`

Comment: @julivico I have added the image of the error in the post...please do see

Comment: @AdemÖztaş Yes, i have tried to install the mysqldb

Comment: You can use https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL as an alternative. It's slower, but works and does not require apt-get installed libraries AFAIK. It also has very similiar API, so You can plug in MysqlDb instead, after You fogure out how to launch it.

Comment: did you do `apt-get update` before `install`

Comment: @julivico I treid update, But it didn't worked...I have attached the error in the post.

Comment: @gulshan raj: i saw it. one question: do your Pi have internet? can you ping google.com?

Comment: @julivico Thanks,actually my pi was connected to internet through a dongle but it was running out of data

Answer (score 0):

So i write a answer, so that the question could be marked as "answered".

The problem was losing internet connection. APT need internet connection to download the packages from source.

For someone, who want to install python module MySQLDB in Debian or Ubuntu:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

If you want to install MySQLDB from pip, you need to install all the prerequisites for python-mysqldb first (for virtualenv)

```
apt-get build-dep python-mysqldb
pip install mysql-python
```